# First Selenium using Maven and Java,

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have written my even first code using Selenium Web driver, Maven and Java.  Can someone give expert opinion if I am in the right direct and if this particular code can be improved.

```
public class myFirstTest {
    @Test
    public void startWebDriver(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.ft.com/home/uk");
        Assert.assertTrue("title should start with World Business", driver.getTitle().equals("World business, finance, and political news from the Financial Times - FT.com"));

        driver.findElement(By.id("ftLogin-signIn")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/form/fieldset[1]/input")).sendKeys("xxx@mail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ftLogin-password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/form/fieldset[3]/p[1]/button")).submit();

        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending is you are learning or creating a test framework for your company there are some pointers.

1. You functions and values for finding elements are not optimal. cssSelector or id is to prefer.

;

```
By.cssSelector("input[id$='ftLogin-username']");
```

or

```
By.id("ftLogin-username");
```

Never use xpath if not is absolutly necessary. Escpecially those dependending on the DOM object. Instead change the webpage implemenation to set an id on the webpage elements.

For the button which doesnt have a unique class or id i would use the text instead

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button:(*'Sign in'*)"));
```

2. If this login part is to be used in several test cases, create a helper class with a login function instead. Otherwise you have to wright the same code over and over again. If a id or xpath where to change you also have to update all your test cases which uses that element.
3. Add an assertion att the end of the test case to verify that the login has been successful.

Comment: All very helpful comments. Very kind of you to take time and write. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the code you have written can be improved.
Considering the fact, you have just started with WebDriver, below are few suggestions-

Avoid using such long xpaths for locating elements. It has lots of
    dependency on DOM. Use short xpaths wherever possible or go for
    using other locators.

You can read data from files(s) required for your tests.(example : username, password)

You can use annotations such as @BeforeClass, @BeforeMethod etc., if you are using any unit testing framework to run your tests such as JUnit, TestNG.

Comment: One things, looking at that Xpath I have written using Firebug, do you think it can be written in  a shorter version manually or do you mean use different locator?   
I have to learn how to access file/s for username and password and noted your annotation point. Thanks again.

Comment: IMHO don't use xpaths at all if you have other locators available.
If you have no other option (say no id, class, name etc) then only go for xpaths.
And yes, you can write shorter xpaths as well, depending on availability of various attributes of an element. You can write your own xpath in firebug and check for its validity as well.